# User detail provaiding IOS app analytics tool

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, analytics

I want an `ios` app analytic which will provide app user details, i already know `google analytic`, `flurry` and some other analytic tools but they wont give any user details, like; how many users viewed a particular product in my app including user profile details.

Comment: What "user details" do you want to collect? If you don't do anonymous user tracking - it may freak many users.

Comment: @IslamQ.  user contact details

Comment: Do they provide that to your app or do you want to fetch from the system (which I don't think you can do)? If the user is in your database and logged in to your app you could just track by their id - and you could easily do that with Flurry.

Comment: @IslamQ. user details will be in our db.

Comment: @IslamQ. is it possible to identify persons in Flurry?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
[Flurry logEvent:@"User viewed product" withParameters:@{@"userID"  : 123,
                                                         @"username": userName
                                                         // more user's info
                                                         @"productID" : 987
                                                         // more prod's info}];
```